# PHP Sorting an array with named keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a $_POST array that i'd like to reformat for processing. A dump of the $_POST looks like this:

```
Array
(
[question_0] => Why Wordpress is the best
[question_0_answer_0] => First Choice
[question_0_answer_1] => Second Choice
[correct0] => question_0_answer_3
[question_0_answer_3] => adrian stinks
[question_1] => Who do you love?
[question_1_answer_0] => First Choice
[question_1_answer_1] => Second Choice
[question_1_answer_2] => Third Choice
[question_2] => What is your name?
[question_2_answer_0] => First Choice
[question_2_answer_1] => Second Choice
[question_2_answer_2] => Third Choice
[quiz_id] => 17
[submit] => Save Quiz
)
```

I would like to sort through and get a sorted array that looks like this:

```
$fields=array(
array(
    type=>radio,
    text=>Why wordpress is the best
    choices=>array(
        array(
            text=>First Choice,
            value=>First Choice,
            is_correct=>FALSE
        ),
        array(
            text=>First Choice,
            value=>First Choice,
            is_correct=>FALSE           
        ),
        array(
            text=>Adrian Stinks,
            value=>Adrian Stinkse,
            is_correct=>TRUE           
        )
    )
),
array(
    type=>page //divider
),
array(
   type=>radio,
    text=>Who do you love?
    choices=>array(
        array(
            text=>First Choice,
            value=>First Choice,
            is_correct=>TRUE
        ),
        array(
            text=>First Choice,
            value=>First Choice,
            is_correct=>TRUE           
        ),
        array(
            text=>Third Choice,
            value=>Third Choice,
            is_correct=>FALSE           
        )
    ) 
),
array(
    type=>page //divider
),
array(
   type=>radio,
    text=>What is your name?
    choices=>array(
        array(
            text=>First Choice,
            value=>First Choice,
            is_correct=>TRUE
        ),
        array(
            text=>First Choice,
            value=>First Choice,
            is_correct=>TRUE           
        ),
        array(
            text=>Third Choice,
            value=>Third Choice,
            is_correct=>FALSE           
        )
    ) 
),
)
```

How would I achieve this kind of sorting? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start by writing some code, and showing it here. Some usefull reading: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php, http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php, http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: You could get closer by posting the inputs as arrays in your form.